# Login Credentials verification error in Visual Studio Using C# and SQL 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using SQL 2012 for Database and Visual studio 2013. I have connect my SQL database with my application. I am using windows forms C#. When i Run the Program
after entering the id and password i got following error Invalid OperaiotnException Code is here

```
 SqlFunctions.loginCheck(int.Parse(txtBox_LoginID.Text), txtBox_LoginPassword.Text);

static public void loginCheck(int user_id,string user_password)
    {
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=lenovo;Initial Catalog=CustomerCareCenter;Integrated Security=True");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand loginVerify = new SqlCommand("select userID,userPassword from [Users] where userID=@user_id and userPassword=@user_password");
            loginVerify.Parameters.Add("@userID", user_id);
            loginVerify.Parameters.Add("@userPassword", user_password);

            loginVerify.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(Exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line you get this exception?

Comment: loginVerify.ExecuteNonQuery(); at this line @SonerGönül

Comment: I did not use parameters.add and I don't know how to use it.  I usually write the whole sql string and put ' before and after any string.  in your case id is integer password is string but I cannot see any '     so is your syntax correct?

Comment: yes there is no syntax error in code @KennethLi